# Using WordPress shortcode in a title

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have some shortcodes which work fine inside a WordPress post or page. Is there anything I can add to functions.php to enable a shortcode to work inside a WordPress post title?

Comment: can you post some example of code ?

Answer (score 10):

You could try adding a filter to the title in the `functions.php` file such as:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Seems to work for me, however it may play havoc with your permalink's and I wouldn't recommend it.

In future WordPress related questions might be better directed at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following filter to `functions.php` as mentioned by [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268669/david-hancock)

```css
add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );
```

However, this approach may not work if you are using the **Yoast SEO plugin**. For that, you need to add the following filter too:

```css
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'do_shortcode' );
```