# Using Shortcodes in WordPress Site Title

Tags: wordpress

Has anyone successfully managed to get shortcodes working in the WordPress site title? (The one that is found under General Settings, not the actual page title).

I've tried adding `add_filter('wp_title', 'do_shortcode');` in the functions.php file of my theme, but it still doesn't seem to do the trick. I also tried using `add_filter('the_title', 'do_shortcode');` instead, but I believe this only works for the page title if I am not mistaken.

The reason behind this is I'm using a dynamic keyword plugin that simply replaces the target shortcode with the target keyword if you use `[dki]`.

Any advice would be much appreciated =)

Comment: Do you use Yoast at all? if so you may need `add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'do_shortcode' );` (duplicate kinda question on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845403/using-wordpress-shortcode-in-a-title).)

Comment: I currently use SEOPress, but if there is no solution for this, then I may have to switch to Yoast instead.

Comment: I'm sure there's hook, eg `seopress_titles_title` ([here](https://www.seopress.org/support/hooks/filter-meta-title/))

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much good sir :)